# Send date with Google Analytics event

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to send custom event data to Google Analytics e.g. a button press, but I'm only sending it once every 24 hours. Therefor I'm trying to send a date along with the events so it would show the date I provide with the event instead of showing the date of the ga('send'). Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to refine your question, and show the code you attempted to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called [Queue Time](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#queueTime)  This will only work with times less than four hours ago. Although i have heard that it does work with older times you may have to test this yourself.

> Used to collect offline / latent hits. The value represents the time delta (in milliseconds) between when the hit being reported occurred and the time the hit was sent. The value must be greater than or equal to 0. **Values greater than four hours may lead to hits not being processed**.

```
ga('set', 'queueTime', 560);
```

Comment: nice one ! was thinking the same thing :) +1